# How do a i+=2 for-loop in Swift?

Tags: swift, for-loop

for example, a Java for-loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i+=1){
   //
}
```

convert to Swift

```
for index in 0..<5 {
}
```

but what if `i+=2`?

I'm new to Swift.. Maybe it's a stupid question, but will be appreciate if you answer it, thx! :-)

Comment: Instead of doing i+=2 in the for statement wht not using i*2 in the for loop ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html

Comment: @Larme thx a lot!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Check this

```
for index in stride(from: 0, to: 5, by: 2){
    print(index)
}
```

Comment: thx a lot ! i got it

Comment: If you want to count up and including the to parameter, then you can 'through' instead of 'to' in above solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way as well.

```
var first = 0
var last = 10
var add = 2
for i in sequence(first: first, next: { $0 + add })
.prefix(while: { $0 <= last }) {
    print(i)

}
```

Output will be: 0,2,4,6,8,10

Answer (score 1):

In case if your for loop was doing something more complex than adding constant value to index each iteration you may use something like that:

Assuming you have this for loop:

```
for(index = initial; condition(index); mutation(index)){
   //
}
```

Where

- `initial` — initial value constant of type `T`
- `condition` — function `(T) -> Bool`, that checks if loop should end
- `mutation` — function `(T) -> T`, that changes index value each iteration

Then it will be:

```
for index in sequence(first: initial, next: { current in
    let next = mutation(current)
    return condition(next) ? next : nil
}) {
   //
}
```